# Regularized (LASSO) probit regression

Tags: r, lasso, regularization, probit

I have a binary variable Y that is a dichotomization of an unknown latent variable, generated by a regression model with normal error. Therefore it makes sense to fit a probit model to Y.
R enables me to do so using the "glm" function.
I would also like to fit a probit model with LASSO penalty.
Using the function "cv.glmnet" I can fit a logistic regularized model to this problem, however I couldn't find a way to fit a probit regularized model in R.

My questions:

1. Is there a simple way to fit a probit regularized model in R?
2. If not, can I fit a logistic one instead (as the probit and logit are quite similar)?

Thanks!

Amit